# urllib post request not working

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to write a python script using **urllib** library which automates the form filling of a website which in turn sends a mail.

I know this since the website was also done by me long back.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
url = "http://saeindiauvce.com/"
values ={'name':'bibhash1970' ,
         'to':'bibhash1996@gmail.com' ,  
          'subject':'just checking' ,            
          'message':'scraping1234' , 
         'submit':'save'}
#print (values)

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respdata = resp.read()

print (respdata)
```

The POST request is not working and I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: What error do you get? For me it looks like it is working.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am not receiving the mail ,  Since the form sends the mail to my account. but if i fill the form via the website directly i receive the mail.

Answer (score 0):

The form in the page you show looks like:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <!--...-->
</form>
```

So you should send the request to `mail.php` and not the index.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
url = "http://saeindiauvce.com/mail.php"
values ={'name':'bibhash1970' ,
         'to':'bibhash1996@gmail.com' ,  
          'subject':'just checking' ,            
          'message':'scraping1234' , 
         'submit':'save'}
#print (values)

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

When running this, I get a 303 error, but the same occurs when I run this in the Firefox browser:

[image: 303 error in Firefox]

when using the network manager.

Demo in the shell:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> url = "http://saeindiauvce.com/mail.php"
>>> values ={'name':'bibhash1970' ,
...          'to':'bibhash1996@gmail.com' ,  
...           'subject':'just checking' ,            
...           'message':'this is a test' , 
...          'submit':'save'}
>>> #print (values)
... 
>>> data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
>>> data = data.encode('utf-8')
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
>>> resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 303: See Other
```

Comment: that gives an HTTP Error 303

Comment: @BibhashSingh: It also gives an error when I run this in the Firefox browser with the same input...

Comment: @BibhashSingh: I just sent you an email with "blablabla". Did you receive it?

Comment: i did receive the mail saying blablabla

Comment: @BibhashSingh: well I think 303 usually means that you are redirected. But in this case that is - afaik - not necessary.

Comment: was the "blablabla" mail u sent , without the redirection in url? i mean was the url which u put = "http://www.saeindiauvce.com" ?

Comment: @BibhashSingh: it was with the code demonstrated in the answer, but with `'message'` mapping on `'blablabla'` instead of `'scraping1234'`. You can test it yourself with a custom message.

Comment: @BibhashSingh: did you fill in `mail.php`. I get the exception as well, but you can ignore that.

Comment: i did not , as for now.

Comment: @BibhashSingh: still not received a message?

Comment: Noo...I did not get it till now